# Function declaration instead of invoking constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, function-declaration, temporary-objects

I expected to initialize object of B here, but instead I got function declaration:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {};

class B { 
    public: 
        B(const A&) { 
        cout << "B: conversion constructor\n"; 
    } 
};

int main()
{
    B b( A() ); //function declaration: B b( A(*)() );
    b.test();
}
```

The output is: *request for member 'test' in 'b', which is of non-class type 'B( A(**)() )'*

Why isn't the constructor invoked in this situation?

Comment: Look up the most vexing parse.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the many cases where the parser thinks that a variable declaration is a function declaration, try writing it as:

```
B b = A() ;  // Now the compiler doesn't think that it's a function declaration
```

Comment: I noticed this, but it's strange that `B b( A() );` isn't recognized as constructor call.

Comment: @RomanVorobiy: It fits exactly the function declaration syntax: It declares a function `b` taking an argument of type `A()` and returning an argument of type `B`.

Comment: Note the other option: `B b{A{}};`